# How to stop a repeating alarm which was triggered in a Broadcast receiver? How to stop it when we unregister the broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

My Code:

```
public class StartupReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

static final String TAG = "SR";

final int startupID = 1111111;
 AlarmManager alarmManager;
Intent i7 ;
PendingIntent ServiceManagementIntent;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    try{

        System.out.println("is Start Up Reciever started????");
             i7 = new Intent(context, CheckRunningApplicationReceiver.class);
             ServiceManagementIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                    startupID, i7, 0);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 
                    5000, ServiceManagementIntent);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Exception : "+e);
        }

    }

   }
```

CheckRunningApplicationReceiver.java

```
public class CheckRunningApplicationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public final String TAG = "CRAR"; // CheckRunningApplicationReceiver

@Override
public void onReceive(Context aContext, Intent anIntent) {

    //code....  


  }

 }
```

Main Activity:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    getBaseContext().getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(
            new Intent("StartupReceiver_Manual_Start"));
}
```

Manifest File:

```
    <receiver android:name=".StartupReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="StartupReceiver_Manual_Start" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**Question 1:** How we can stop the above started receiver - `StartupReceiver`?
When I unregistered the `StartupReceiver`, How we can I stop the repeating alarm?
Could some one help me out on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to cancel the Alarm using AlarmManager and AlarmId. I am just giving you the sample code,Please change it according to your requirement.

```
 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent intent=new Intent(this,AlarmManagerBroadcast.class);
    PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,alarmid,intent,0);
    alarmManager .cancel(pi);
```

If you have any query please let know.

Comment: Hi @Vivek, It worked!!! Stopping of alaram is working. But one more answer I needed. Could u please help me out on this?                         I have started the Reciever as getBaseContext().getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(
    new Intent("StartupReceiver_Manual_Start"));                                      How we can stop this receiver?

Comment: If have declared the receiver in the manifest. you cant unregister that receiver. If you created the receiver locally means in an activity. You can do that. Any query?